# Cakephp find null

Tags: list, cakephp, find

I want to get everyone who has a null field.

I tried the following but it doesn't return anything.

```
$plato = $this->Platos->find('all',[
            'conditions' => ['alergia_id' => null]
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

> In SQL `null` is not equal `(=)` to anything—not even to another
>   `null`. According to the three-valued logic of SQL, the result of
>   `null = null` is not true but unknown. SQL has the `is [not] null`
>   predicate to test if a particular value is null.

https://modern-sql.com/feature/is-distinct-from

This is the solution.

```
$plato = $this->Platos->find('all',[
            'conditions' => ['alergia_id IS null']
        ]);
```